# How to send all selected values to a NSDictionary to use in another ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I am trying to send an array that loaded with uitableviewcell selected values as dictionary from a viewcontroller (ServicetypesViewController) to load in another array of other viewcontroller(JobcreationViewController) by tapping the done button.

The existing way implemented only sending 1 value by using objctedAtIndex:i and it's sending only 1 value without any crashes

but when I wanted to send multiple selected values with "selectedServiceType" NSDictionary to Jobcreationcell by using a forkey it's crashes and throwing the following execemption.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c065da90'
```

### Getting Selected values and loading to "selected_ids" array. (ServicetypesViewController)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

     if(_selectedIndexes == nil)

    {

        self.selectedIndexes = [NSMutableArray array];



    }



    if([_selectedIndexes containsObject:indexPath])

    {

        [_selectedIndexes  removeObject:indexPath];

        [selected_ids removeObject:[arrayOfServiceTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSLog(@"SELECTEDIDS%@",selected_ids);
    }

      else

    {

        [_selectedIndexes addObject:indexPath];

        NSLog(@"_selectedIndexes%@",_selectedIndexes);

        [selected_ids addObject:[arrayOfServiceTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSLog(@"SELECTEDIDS%@",selected_ids);

    }

}
```

### Done Button Event when sending whole selected dictionary (ServicetypesViewController)

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonAction:(id)sender

{

    NSDictionary *selectedServiceTypeDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

   selectedServiceTypeDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:selected_ids forKey:@"selected_services"];

    [self.selectedServiceTypeDelegate getSelectedServiceType:selectedServiceTypeDict];

    NSLog(@"selectedServiceTypeDict%@",selectedServiceTypeDict);

    [self navigationLeftButtonAction:self.navigationLeftButton];
}
```

### Get the data to (jobcreationViewController)

```
-(void)getSelectedServiceType:(NSDictionary *)selectedServicesType

{

    selectedServiceType = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[selectedServicesType valueForKey:@"selected_services"], nil];

    NSLog(@"SST%@",selectedServiceType);

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Even App crashes I can see the *NSLog - SST* responses correctly. I tried many methods but only I can send 1 value out of other selected values. Please help me, by providing code snippets according to my codes in answer.
Thanks in Advance.

### Edited part

### Following are the codes how can I send single value to jobcreationviewcontroller

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *selectedServiceTypeDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

    for(int i=0; i<selected_ids.count; i++)
    {

        if([_selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:i ])
        {
            selectedServiceTypeDict = selected_ids[i];

        }




    }

    [self.selectedServiceTypeDelegate getSelectedServiceType:selectedServiceTypeDict];
    NSLog(@"selectedServiceTypeDict%@",selectedServiceTypeDict);
    [self navigationLeftButtonAction:self.navigationLeftButton];

}

-(void)getSelectedServiceType:(NSDictionary *)selectedServicesType

{

    selectedServiceType = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:selectedServicesType, nil];

    NSLog(@"SST%@",selectedServiceType);

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: check on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/4831524

Comment: @AntonyRaphel I think this is not my exact problem, I can send single selected item successfully to next view controller by tapping done button.. My exact requirement is to send multiple values.

Comment: Does this return multiple values? `NSLog(@"SELECTEDIDS%@",selected_ids);`

Comment: Yes, It's returning exact selected values...

Comment: Any Ideas guys... @AntonyRaphel can I Post the response.. any ideas?

Comment: check with below given ans

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161592/discussion-between-antony-raphel-and-fido).